# C programming, using memory

Tags: c, memory

I have a main function and it has global array

```
unsigned int    MainArray [800];
```

then the program calls function which has local

```
unsigned int    FunctionArray [400];
```

and I have not enough space in memory.

However  the `MainArray` is not used while the function is called and inside data is not important, also `FunctionArray` is not required after function is used.

Is any way how `FunctionArray` can be declared over same memory allocation that the `MainArray` uses?
When I declare `MainArray [800];` inside main then later on other functions can’t access the data.

Comment: Could you be a bit more descriptive on what you are really trying to do?

Comment: Make `FunctionArray`  a global, or make it a pointer `FunctionTab` and use `calloc` to get a heap zone. Also, for which operating system are you coding, with which compiler? Show some source code!

Comment: `MainArray` is not used while the function is called, so why do you need to define it global, do you need the array for functions which has been called later in the program??

Comment: Do you mean that `MainArray` is local to `main` (i.e. not global) ?

Comment: Are you sure these 400 integers break the back of the camel? If you are programming for a calculator wristwatch, such economy might be appropriate, otherwise you are likely to have memory leaks elsewhere.

Comment: Looks like the stack space is insufficient.  Is the function recursive or mutually recursive?  What platform are you running on?

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a variable inside `main()`, this *doesn't make it a global* variable, it's a variable local to `main()`. Unless you pass a pointer to it around, other functions can't access it.

You seem to ask for a global array. Just declare it *outside* `main()` and every function can access it.

Global variables, however, should be carefully considered since they vulnerate the rule of information hiding/encapsulation (that may be the reason nobody taught you they exist), nevertheless there are sometimes good reasons to use them (especially on devices where memory is a scarce resource which seems to be the case for you).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data from the `mainArray` on the later state of the program, i.e, after the execution of the `function`, then, you can't say the "data of the mainArray is not important while the function is called" because it's important afterwards.

If you are thinking of a way for "FunctionArray can be declared over same memory allocation that the MainArray uses", then even if there WOULD HAVE BEEN a way, the data of `mainArray` would have been destroyed which you will be needing in later program as you said.

If you don't need the data of main in later state, you can do one thing,

define the array as a pointer outside the `main()`,

```
unsigned int * MainArray;
```

then allocate it dynamically with required size in `main()`. When the need of the array is finished, just `free` the memory. The space will be available for farther allocations.

If you need the `mainArray` after the execution of the function having the `functionArray`,and not before; just allocate the memory for the `mainArray` after the function has been executed. and use the local `functionArray` as the pointer as well, in the function and `free` the memory before the control gets back from the function. This way your program doesn't occupy the space for the `mainArray` while executing that function, and when the function is done executing, `functionArray` is not occupying any space.

But if you need mainArray, both before and after the function execution, I think there is no way you could solve the memory problem..

Comment: From the function I could simply use global main function array MainArray [800] and process the data ;
but the functions array actually needs to be in rows FunctionArray  [10] [24]; @deb_rider

Comment: What do i use here to write more information, comment or answer the question?

Comment: To add more infos to your question, edit the question and mention the edits in the comment.

Comment: If you need the `mainArray` after the execution of the function having the `functionArray`,and not before; just allocate the memory for the `mainArray` after the function has been executed. and use the local `functionArray` as the pointer as well, in the function and `free` the memory before the control gets back from the function. This way your program doesn't occupy the space for the `mainArray` while executing that function, and when the function is done executing, `functionArray` is not occupying any space.

Comment: But if you need `mainArray` both before and after the function execution, I'm afraid, there is no way to solve the memory problem.

Comment: I don't need data form mainArray until function executes but i need location there because later on all is copied to EEprom. What i think now is really how to use MainArray [800] as FunctionArray [4][200].

Comment: you can do that.. try indexing for `functionArray[i][j]` as `mainArray[i*200+j]`. that' it. got it??

Answer (score 0):

you can use the arrays base pointer to access the array's memory space in other functions.
you declare a array

```
unsigned int    MainArray [800];
```

Then if you pass `MainArray` as parameter to function and receive it as,

```
returnType somefunction(unsigned int   * FunctionArray, ...)
{

}
```

Then you can use the same memory in both main function and array. but in function make sure that you access `FunctionArray` only within its size limit of 400. This will enable you to access same memory in both functions as array.
You can even allocate memory to arrays dynamically, if they are needed in program in sequence and not at same time. you can use `malloc` or `alloca`.

Comment: What if `mainArray` is fully loaded with 800 elements??? The data will be compromised, right?

Comment: @deb_rider ya. but the OP asked `Is any way how FunctionArray can be declared over same memory allocation that the MainArray uses?`. may be OP wants to access same memory. May be the array in main is used after function call only.

Comment: Then shouldn't he just allocate the memory for the `mainArray` after the function has been executed. and shouldn't he use the local `functionArray` as the pointer as well in the function and `free` the memory before the control gets back from the array??